# Using Bluetooth headset for voice calling on Nexus 4 Stock

Tags: bluetooth, calls

I know that people over the net have reported that they were able to place a voice call using one of their Bluetooth headsets.

I have a Sony Ericcsson HBH-DS970 headset which pairs with my Nexus nicely and I am able to use it for audio with no issues, but while placing a call I have no option to use the headset instead of the default mic and earpiece of the phone.

Am I missing some of the settings that make this option is available for me?

The Bluetooth setting says that the headset is connected as "phone audio" as well as for "media audio".

I guess "phone audio" means voice calling through this headset (which isn't working for me) and media audio is the music audio (mp3 players and normal android sounds) that's working fine for me.

Then why am I seeing no option for placing voice call through the headset?